# How can I get the name of the current app to the apex controller?

Tags: apex, controller, app

I need to get the name of the current app in the controller. So far I'm trying:

```
public static String getAppName() {

       UserAppInfo userAppInfo = [SELECT Id, AppDefinitionId FROM UserAppInfo WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
       AppDefinition appDefinition = [SELECT DurableId, Label FROM AppDefinition Where DurableId = :userAppInfo.AppDefinitionId LIMIT 1];
       return appDefinition.Label;
    }
```

But Im getting 3 errors:

```
Line 1: No such column 'AppDefinitionId' on entity 'UserAppInfo'
Line 2: Invalid type: AppDefinition
Line 3: Variable does not exist: appDefinition
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to what I may be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the API version of your class. AppDefinition is only available in 38.0 or greater, and the AppDefinitionId field is only available in 43.0 or greater. The code you provided works as an execute anonymous script, so I presume it's simply a version problem.

Comment: And `UserAppInfo.AppDefinitionId` requires v43.0 or greater.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor Ah, that wasn't in the docs I checked. I'll update.